# Sniff packets in Visual studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I am writing application that is using UdpClient to send and receive data, but i am getting many data sent wrong. I need to figure out how my data is transfered between client and server. So i need some sniffer plugin for Visual Studio cause i don't want to use some heavy tools like WireShark. So is it possible to track received and transmitted data in my application?

Comment: One thing to remember with udp is theres no send/receive its like using snail mail, you post the packet, you hope it gets there, theres no tracking - if data is wrong, is it because your packets aren't making it to destination?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the ["Network Tracing" feature built into .NET itself](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hyb3xww8(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
<configuration>
  <system.diagnostics>
    <sources>
      <source name="System.Net" tracemode="includehex" maxdatasize="1024">
        <listeners>
          <add name="System.Net"/>
        </listeners>
      </source>
      <source name="System.Net.Sockets">
        <listeners>
          <add name="System.Net"/>
        </listeners>
      </source>
    </sources>
    <switches>
      <add name="System.Net" value="Verbose"/>
      <add name="System.Net.Sockets" value="Verbose"/>
    </switches>
    <sharedListeners>
      <add name="System.Net"
        type="System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener"
        initializeData="network.log"
      />
    </sharedListeners>
    <trace autoflush="true"/>
  </system.diagnostics>
</configuration>
```